# How to disable x-frame-options for a Chrome instance?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I run Chrome with the flags `--disable-web-security --user-data-dir` in order to disable the same origin policy and run some tests, and it really allows me to make JS post requests to some external URIs.

But when I try to include an iframe with an external URL as `src` in my HTML page, I get the following error message: "Refused to display 'https://trap-your-trip.com/search' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'."

Any way to pass it **without installing any extensions**? (Maybe another flag)

Comment: "X-Frame-Options: sameorigin" prevents iframing external sites. Bypassing may risk security and should be done with consent or legitimate access.

Comment: Have you tried `--disable-site-isolation-trials`?

Answer (score 0):

### Change the HTTP response header

You would need to change the HTTP response header to allow for external website `iframe` URLs. The current website you're testing on doesn't allow you to display external websites within an `iframe`, thus you'd have to change this setting before testing further.

If you are not able to edit the HTTP response header, you're more than likely running tests which the website host is trying to prevent.